# How to simulate stock prices with impact of news

Tags: python, function, numpy, random, simulation

I'm writing a function that generates simulated stock market prices and part of the code incorporates the impact of news (e.g. political turmoil, a natural disaster) on share price over a number of days.

```py
# Set up the default_rng from Numpy
rng = np.random.default_rng()

def news(chance, volatility):
    '''
    Simulate the impact of news on stock prices with %chance
    '''
    # Choose whether there's news today
    news_today = rng.choice([0,1], p=chance)
    if news_today:
        # Calculate m and drift
        m = rng.normal(0,0.3)
        drift = m * volatility
        # Randomly choose the duration
        duration = rng.integers(7,7*12)
        final = np.zeros(duration)
        for i in range(duration):
            final[i] = drift
        return final
    else:
        return np.zeros(duration)
```

I'm getting several error messages, one of them being:

```py
news_today = rng.choice([0,1], p=chance)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `p` parameter needs a length that matches the length of the list of choices. That is, you need a chance associated with each choice. Try:

```
news_today = rng.choice([0,1], p=[chance, 1 - chance])
```

Comment: after implenting this, I get an error message on the line `return np.zeros(duration)`

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'duration' referenced before assignment`

Comment: @codemachine98 make duration a global variable by taking it out of the function and placing it above it instead.